# Is it possible to implement dynamic notifications on Apple Watch without a launchable app?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I've designed a custom notification for an app I'm working on for Apple Watch. The notifications look good but because of the current technical limitations I don't want to build a launchable app or glance until I have mic and speaker access. Is it possible to display dynamic notifications without having an app icon on the home screen of the watch or is the watch app mandatory to have a dynamic notification at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you will need to add a dynamic Notification scene in your Watch app.

If you want to read more information about this I'd refer you to this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH6-SW1

Comment: Did you see triggering notification either remote or local notification in watch ? Did you able to do this without Payload which is static. I want local notification and it should not be payload static file. Tell me how to do this